# Git: After merge 2 branges the stashed changes applied to both

Tags: git, git-merge, git-stash

Is that normal?

Let me explain a bit more..
I have 2 branches, say BranchA and BranchB.
I want to merge these 2 branches but i have some changes in BranchA that I want to keep away and revisit, so I stash these files.
Then I merge A with B (fix conflicts, commit push etc)

Then I checkout BranchA again and Stash pop.

The result is that now I see these changes as uncommitted changes in both branches!! Is that to be expected??

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use stash, this is what the stage (index) for.
Choose which files or part of files (hunks) to add to the stage and commit them.

hunks are part of files that you want to add. for example if you have 5 changes to file you can choose to add 0-5 changes (to pick few of them and not all of them).

The file system + staging are are **Shared** between all your branches **unless** you use git-new-workdir

Comment: You confused me! it seems you are suggesting a different approach, but the question remains about git-stash...

Comment: To be more clear.
Working folder + stage area (stash store the content of those sections) are shared between all your branches when you switch branches. So if you save to stash and pop it exist for all branches

Comment: what you describe is the default Beauvoir. Read more here: https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing